# Zend DB - Flush temporary tables

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

One part of my application is querying `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` which throws an exception if a current connection already has a temporary table. Ideally, I would just add `IF NOT EXISTS`, but unfortunately, I can't edit the code at that particular part of the application.

So, what would be the other best way to make sure TMP tables for the current connection are cleared? I tried using

```
$this->_connection->closeConnection();
```

but that also throws an exception on the first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to flush tmp tables without exceptions by executing the following code:

```
$this->_connection->commit();
$this->_connection->closeConnection();
$this->_connection->beginTransaction();
```